# r pthread-like functions

Tags: multithreading, r

I want to do some multithreading with R. I'm used to C pthread functionalities. What I want to do is:

```
#initialisation
n=10
A <- numeric(n)

i=c(1:n/2)

# compute some indexes using the one function fun1
# equivalent in C with correct initialisation of t1 and attr: 
## pthread_create(&t1, &attr, fun1, i)
A[i] <- fun1(length(i))

# compute other indexes using another function fun2
# equivalent in C with correct initialisation of t2 and attr: 
## pthread_create(&t2, &attr, fun2, i)
A[-i] <- fun2(n-length(i))

# wait for the thread to finish
# equivalment in C:
## pthread_join(t1); pthread_join(t2)

# do something with the result
A
```

The two functions fun1 and fun2 are totally independent I don't think use `fork()` is appropriate as I want to wait for all thread to be finished before doing the next step. with the result of the 2 functions `fun1` and `fun2`.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have done any research about parallelization in R. Have a look at [CRAN Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html). However, first you should try and optimize efficiency of `fun1` and `fun2`. Potential speed gains there are of orders of magnitude (you could even use Rcpp).

Comment: I may have not be as explicite as I thought. I want some generic code to understand how to redo such things. In my case, both `fun1` and `fun2` uses `apply` function, which is hard to optimize. Furthermore, I have lots of stuff to do in `fun1` and `fun2` and i want some code that can easily be extended to a greater number of function (say `fun1`, `fun2` and `fun3`)

Comment: If they use `apply` that's what you need to optimize. After all, `apply` is just an R loop. If you can`t use vector algebra or specialized functions (like `colSums`) then you should look into implementing them with Rcpp. However, there is a number of posibilities for parallelization in R. Do some research and then ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

- Do you loop over the `i`? If yes, then could you also evaluate `fun1` and `fun2` for each `i` idependently? In that case construct a loop over the `i` using the `foreach` package together with a parallel backend like `doMC`. Like

  ```
  require(foreach)
  require(doMC)
  A <- foreach( i = 1:(n/2), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {c(fun1(i),fun2(i))}
  ```
- Otherwise, construct a pseudofunction that you will pass a switch to, telling it which of `fun1`  `fun2` to run

  ```
  switchingFun <- function( .., selFun=1){
    if(selFun == 1){ fun1( ...)} else {fun2(... )
  }
  ```

  Also construct a list with the arguemnts to fun1 and fun2. And put this into the `foreach( selFun in 1:2) %dopar% {switchingFun( arguments[[selFun]], selFun)}` loop. (The `...` are pretty darn useful, I just tried that out!)

  You will /might / should take a look at the functions you call, you might need to do something to the argument list before passing it (get correct types, disentangle it...) in the `switchingFun` function.
- The `A[-i]` will (likely) not work the way you want. In R, saying `A[-i]` selects all elements that are *not* indexed by `i`...

Comment: Thanks. I don't loop over `i` otherwise i would have used `mclapply()` or other functions from `parallel` package. I didn't think of the pseudo function. I think it is appropriate to my case.

Comment: @Manu Yeah, after reading your code again it seems obvious ;) I also just thought of the pseudo function, I also learn something new every day. It is also the first time I used the `...` variable, good stuff!

Also: If you use apply in fun1 and fun2, it is really easy to do the foreach stuff in there!